# Adding a physical ethernet interface to kvm qemu bridge

Tags: networking, network-interface, ethernet, bridge, libvirt

I'm following [this excellent article to use bridged networking with libvirt and KVM](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-use-bridged-networking-with-libvirt-and-kvm), however there are some fundamental knowledge I'm lacking for me to fully understand/follow it.

The article says,

> - No physical interfaces should ever be added to the virbr0 bridge, since it uses NAT to provide connectivity.
> - Virtual interfaces will be added to the bridge when we create and launch virtual machines.

and most importantly,

> - you can’t use your main ethernet interface when adding physical ethernet interface to the bridge.
> - thus we have to use an additional interface.

I'm not too sure about the relations between physical interfaces, virtual interfaces, main interface and additional interface, thus when the article says he is using an additional interface, enp0s29u1u1, an interface provided by an ethernet to usb adapter. I'm totally lost what additional interface **I** should be using for *my case*, which is a vanilla Debian, with a single ethernet card.

Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A "physical interface" refers to an actual network device on your computer -- that is, something into which you can plug an ethernet cable, or a wireless network device.

A "virtual interface" refers to network interfaces that aren't associated with a specific physical device: so, vlan interfaces, bridges, tun/tap interfaces, etc.

Your "main interface" is the network interface with which you system's primary ip address (and default route) is associated.

An "additional interface", in this context, is any physical interface other than your main interface.

---

These two statements...

> - No physical interfaces should ever be added to the virbr0 bridge, since it uses NAT to provide connectivity.
> - Virtual interfaces will be added to the bridge when we create and launch virtual machines.

...are correct. The `virbr0` bridge is associated with the libvirt "default" network and uses NAT to connect virtual machines to the outside world; you would not want to add a physical interface to this bridge.

Libvirt creates tun/tap devices when you launch virtual machines and adds them to the bridge.

However, the following statement...

> - You can’t use your main ethernet interface when adding physical ethernet interface to the bridge.

...is a bit of a simplification. You *can* use your main ethernet interface as part of a bridge, but the procedure is a little more complicated than when using a secondary interface (and is a great way to accidentally disable your internet connectivity).  Broadly, you need to:

1. Create a bridge device
2. Add your ethernet interface to the bridge
3. Configure the bridge device with the ip address that was previously associated with your main interface

For example, on my system, `eth0` looks like this:

```
# ip addr show eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:9b:a0:2a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp1s0
    inet 192.168.122.64/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 3570sec preferred_lft 3570sec
    inet6 fe80::d6:992e:d74a:c05a/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

That's the only physical interface on my system. We're also going to need to know our default route:

```
# ip route
default via 192.168.122.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100
192.168.122.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.64 metric 100
```

To add `eth0` to a bridge, I would first create a bridge device:

```
# ip link add br-example type bridge
```

Then add `eth0` to the bridge and remove any existing addresses from `eth0`:

```
# ip link set eth0 master br-example
# ip addr flush eth0
```

Add the address that used to be on `eth0` to `br-example` and restore the default route:

```
# ip addr add 192.168.122.64/24 dev br-example
# ip link set br-example up
# ip route add default via 192.168.122.1
```

At this point (a) I have a bridge `br-example`, (b) `eth0` is a member of this bridge, and (c) I still have connectivity (via the brdige) out `eth0`. Following the instructions in your linked article, I could create a libvirt network associated with `br-example` and start attaching virtual machines to it; from a network perspective, these machines would look like any other device physically attached to the local network.

Of course, the above procedure doesn't result in persistent changes; how do that differs by distribution and the article to which you've linked provides a good overview of the process.

Comment: thanks a lot!!! The network I need to change is for a machine that I'm ssh'ing into, so I compiled all steps into a shell script, then run `ssh my-svr sudo bash -x /tmp/br-example.sh`, and it worked like a charm! thanks again for your high quality answer, 'cause a tiny mistake will cost me to loose my connection!

Comment: I don't understand why VMware/VirtualBox no need such bridge.